# ASP.NET Core Web API - JWT authentication always throwing 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am implementing JWT authentication in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API. I have this code:

Models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}


public class RefreshToken
{
    //[JsonIgnore]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

TokenGeneratorService:

```
public class TokenGeneratorService : ITokenGeneratorService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public TokenGeneratorService(IConfiguration configuration, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateToken(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var authClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
            //new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
            //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)
            //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Uri, avatar)
        };

        //Gets the roles of the logged in user and adds it to Claims
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtSettings:SecretKey"]));

        // Specifying JWTSecurityToken Parameters
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken
        (audience: _configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
         issuer: _configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
         claims: authClaims,
         expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
         signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }

    public int? ValidateJwtToken(string token)
    {
        if (token == null)
            return null;

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtSettings:SecretKey"]);

        try
        {
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

            var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
            var userId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);
            return userId;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Guid GenerateRefreshToken()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

TokenRepository:

```
public class TokenRepository : ITokenRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public TokenRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetUserByRefreshToken(Guid token, string userId)
    {
        // Check for user Id
        var user = await _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.RefreshToken == token && u.Id == userId);
        //var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshToken == token && u.Id == userId);
        //FirstOrDefaultAsync
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"User with Id {userId} does not exist");
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

Login:

```
public async Task<Response<LoginResponseDto>> Login(LoginRequestDto model)
{
    var response = new Response<LoginResponseDto>();
    var getUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    var loggedUser = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName).Select(m => m.UserName).FirstOrDefault();

    var user1 = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

    var loggedUserRole = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(getUser);
    var loggedUserRoleName = loggedUserRole[0].ToString();

    if (loggedUserRoleName == "Customer" || loggedUserRoleName == "CustomerUser")
    {
        var validityResult = await ValidateUser(model);

        if (!validityResult.Successful)
        {
            response.Successful = false;
            return response;
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var refreshToken = _tokenGenerator.GenerateRefreshToken();

        user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
        user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7); //sets refresh token for 7 days
        user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;

        var result = new LoginResponseDto()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Token = await _tokenGenerator.GenerateToken(user),
            RefreshToken = refreshToken,
            User = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),
            Roles = roles,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
        };

        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return response;
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
public static class AuthenticationServiceExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                .UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtSettings:SecretKey"])),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
     
        services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.SaveToken = true;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;

       });
        
    }
}

public static class DIServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Service Injections Here -- Auth
        services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
        services.AddScoped<ITokenGeneratorService, TokenGeneratorService>();
        services.AddScoped<ITokenRepository, TokenRepository>();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAuthentication(configuration);
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
  
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHsts();
app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();

string? port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port))
{
    app.Urls.Add("http://*:" + port);
}
app.Run();
```

I send a `POST` request to `Login` and I got the token. But when I use the token for querying any other endpoint using Postman (added the token in authorization/JWT in Postman), I got this error:

> 401 unauthorized

every time.

Where have I got it wrong and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Probably need more info on the error, but are you using the right token in your api calls - the access token, not the id_token

Answer (score 0):

When you get a 401 error in postman, you can see the error message in `WWW-Authenticate`:
[image]

And how did you generate the token? You can verify your token is valid in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/):
[image]

Put the value of `JwtSettings:SecretKey` into `VERIFY SIGNATURE`, and then paste your token into `Encoded` for verification to see if there is a problem.

I made a simple example, you can refer to it.

appsetting.json:

```
"JWT": {
    "SecretKey": "Yh2k7QSu4l8CZg5p6X3Pna9L0Miy4D3Bvt0JVr87UcOj69Kqw5R2Nmf4FWs03Hdx",
    "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
    "Audience": "JWTServicePostmanClient"
}
```

Models:

```
public class Users
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Tokens
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.ConfigureAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJWTManagerRepository, JWTManagerRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHsts();
app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();
string? port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port))
{
    app.Urls.Add("http://*:" + port);
}

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Extension:

```
public static class AuthenticationServiceExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                    .UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:SecretKey"])),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddSingleton(tokenValidationParameters);

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.SaveToken = true;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;

       });

    }
}
```

I created an `IJWTManagerRepository` interface to authenticate users and generate JSON Web Tokens:

```
public interface IJWTManagerRepository
{
    Tokens Authenticate(Users users);
}

public class JWTManagerRepository : IJWTManagerRepository
{
    Dictionary<string, string> UsersRecords = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "user1","password1"},
        { "user2","password2"},
        { "user3","password3"},
    };

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public JWTManagerRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public Tokens Authenticate(Users users)
    {
        if (!UsersRecords.Any(x => x.Key == users.Name && x.Value == users.Password))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Else we generate JSON Web Token
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:SecretKey"]);

        var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            //Required if ValidateIssuer = true
            Issuer = configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            //Required if ValidateAudience = true
            Audience = configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
            
        return new Tokens { Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token) };

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IJWTManagerRepository _jWTManager;

    public UsersController(IJWTManagerRepository jWTManager)
    {
        this._jWTManager = jWTManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<string> Get()
    {
        var users = new List<string>
        {
            "Satinder Singh",
            "Amit Sarna",
            "Davin Jon"
        };

        return users;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate(Users usersdata)
    {
        var token = _jWTManager.Authenticate(usersdata);

        if (token == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return Ok(token);
    }
}
```

Test Result:

Get Token:
[image]

Use token to access other endpoints:
[image]

Comment: I've updated the post with the initial code. WWW-Authenticate  gives  Bearer error="invalid_token"

Comment: Hi @Ayobamilaye, it looks like you're using Identity and many extra models, but there are a few that you don't provide. Since the code you provided is a bit complicated, I can't confirm whether you have used the correct Token to access. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? If your project does not contain sensitive information, you can publish the project in GitHub so that it can be cloned to find your issue.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am using Identity

Comment: Hi @Ayobamilaye, I used Identity to test according to your code, and there is still no problem. You need to provide more details. Also, you see `Bearer error="invalid_token"` in postman, but what is the `error_description`? You didn't say.